# Explain the implementation of Euler's Totient Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I have seen this code in a coding platform to efficiently calculate the euler's totient for different values.
I am not being able to understand this implementation. I really want to learn this. Could anyone please help me explain this?

```
for(int i = 1; i < Maxn; i++) { // phi[1....n] in n * log(n)
   phi[i] += i;
   for(int j = 2 * i; j < Maxn; j += i) {
      phi[j] -= phi[i]; 
   }
}
```

Comment: Is there some reason this has the wolfram-mathematica tag? That isn't Mathematica code.

Answer (score 6):

First, lets note that for prime values `p`, `phi(p) = p - 1`. This should be fairly intuitive, because all numbers less than a prime must be coprime to said prime. So then we start into our outer for loop:

```
for(int i = 1; i < Maxn; i++) { // phi[1....n] in n * log(n)
   phi[i] += i;
```

Here we add the value of `i` to `phi(i)`. For the prime case, this means we need `phi(i)` to equal `-1` beforehand, and all other `phi(i)` must be adjusted further to account for the number of coprime integers. Focusing on the prime case, lets convince ourselves that these do equal `-1`.

If we step through the loop, at case `i=1`, we'll end up iterating over all other elements in our inner loop, subtracting `1`.

```
   for(int j = 2 * i; j < Maxn; j += i) {
      phi[j] -= phi[i]; 
   }
```

For any other values to be subtracted `j` must equal the prime `p`. But that would require `j = 2 * i + i * k` to equal `p`, for some iteration `k`. That cannot be, because `2 * i + i * k == i * (2 + k)` implying that `p` can be divided evenly by `i`, which it cannot (since its prime). Thus, all `phi(p) = p - 1`.

For non-prime `i`, we need to subtract out the number of coprime integers. We do this in the inner for loop. Reusing the formula from before, if `i` divides `j`, we get `j / i = (2 + k)`. So every value less than `i` can be multiplied by `(2 + k)` to be less than `j`, yet have a common factor of `(2 + k)` with j (thus, not coprime).

However, if we subtracted out `(i - 1)` multiples containing `(2 + k)` factors, we'd count the same factors multiple times. Instead, we only count those which are coprime to `i`, or in other words `phi(i)`. Thus, we are left with `phi(x) = x - phi(factor_a) - phi(factor_b) ...` to account for all the `(2 + k_factor)` multiples of coprimes less than said factor, which now share a factor of `(2 + k_factor)` with `x`.

Putting this into code gives us exactly what you have above:

```
for(int i = 1; i < Maxn; i++) { // phi[1....n] in n * log(n)
   phi[i] += i;
   for(int j = 2 * i; j < Maxn; j += i) {
      phi[j] -= phi[i]; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By the way, just out of interest, there's also an `O(n)` algorithm to achieve the same. We know Euler's product formula for the totient is

```
phi(n) = n * product(
  (p - 1) / p)

  where p is a distinct prime that divide n
```

For example,

```
phi(18) = 18 * (
  (2-1)/2 * (3-1)/3)

        = 18 * 2/6
        = 18 * 1/3

  = 6
```

Now consider a number `m = n * p` for some prime `p`.

```
phi(n) = n * product(
  (p' - 1) / p')

  where p' is a distinct prime that divide n
```

If `p` divides `n`, since `p` already appears in the calculation for `phi(n)`, we do not need to add it to the product section, rather we just add it to the initial multiplier

```
phi(m) = phi(p * n) = p * n * product(
  (p' - 1) / p')

       = p * phi(n)
```

Otherwise, if `p` does not divide `n`, we need to use the new prime,

```
phi(m) = phi(p * n) = p * n * product(
  (p' - 1) / p') * (p - 1) / p

       = p * (p - 1) / p * n * product(
  (p' - 1) / p')

       = (p - 1) * phi(n)
```

Either way, we can calculate the totient of a number multiplied by a prime only from the prime and the number's own totient, which can be aggregated in `O(n)` by repeatedly multiplying the numbers we've generated so far by the next prime we find until we reach `Maxn`. We find the next prime by incrementing an index to the successor we haven't recorded a totient for (prime generation here is a benefit).